# Correct encoding for x86 ADD instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I manually encode the following instruction:

```
add [di], al
```

And according to my understanding of the x86 documentation, the corresponding machine code should be:

```
00 07
```

When compiling the above code with `nasm`, I get the following:

```
# echo "add [di], al" > test.asm && nasm test.asm && xxd -ps test
0005
```

The same happens when compiling with `as`.

I suspect this has something to do with 16/32/64 bit encoding, but I cannot find information around this.

Comment: The  modr/m byte is different between 16 and 32 bit mode.  You have encoded the instruction as if it was `add [edi], al` in 32 bit mode.  This is not correct.  Refer to the Intel SDM for the encoding of memory operands in 16 bit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to [this reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek64-abc.html#modrm_byte_16) `00 07` corresponds to `add [bx], al` and `00 05` is correct for `add [di], al`.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  I was using the 32/64 bit modr/m encoding and not the 16 bit encoding.  In 32 bit, 0x05 is `BP`.

Comment: @fizixx, Where do you get that in 32 bit, 0x05 is `BP`? For one thing, it would be EBP. But even that’s not right. It’s actually disp32.

Comment: @prl yes you are right.  I was generalizing that the 0b101 was pointing to the "BP" section, but in fact the 0b101 for 32-bit mode and mod 0b00 is a special case for 32-bit displacement as you mention.